# Python keras - getting error with model layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am new on classification problems using artificial neural networks

I have a classification problem where the input data are 8 columns with decimal values Which are measures and the output data are 8 columns with integer values which are objects

```
INPUTS

785.39 6.30 782.75 771.82 7.53 -94.86 378.66 771.82
.
.
.

OUTPUTS

  8     9     5      7     3     1      6      2
  .
  .
  .
```

The records for the training data are 800 and for the test data are 200

This is the code

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
datasetTrain = numpy.loadtxt("train.csv", delimiter=",")
datasetTest = numpy.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",")

X_train = datasetTrain[:,0:7]
y_train = datasetTrain[:,8:15]

X_test = datasetTest[:,0:7]
y_test = datasetTest[:,8:15]

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense((5593, 785), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return model

model = baseline_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=400, 
batch_size=200, verbose=25)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Baseline Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proyecto.py", line 29, in <module>
    model = baseline_model()
  File "proyecto.py", line 24, in baseline_model
    model.add(Dense((5593, 785), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Which is the best model for this data?

Comment: if one of these answers solved your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
model.add(Dense((5593, 785), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
```

Is wrong, the first parameter to Dense is the number of output neurons, which should be a scalar, not a tuple or vector. If you want a 2D-shaped output, then you can use a Reshape layer to reshape the output and do the following:

```
model.add(Dense(5593 * 785, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
model.add(Reshape((5593, 785)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After your first layer `model.add(Dense(7...`, the output of that layer has dimension `7` (7 output neurons). The next layer can handle that 7-neuron layer as input automatically. But you are then telling Keras that the next layer should have output neurons of `(5593, 785)` when it is looking for another single number.

Do you get what you want by changing `model.add(Dense((5593, 785)...`

to either

```
model.add(Dense(1...
```

or

```
model.add(Dense(n...
```

(where `n` is the number of possible levels of the categorical variable you're trying to classify?

Answer (score 0):

```
model = Sequential()
```

num_pixels=img_height*img_width

```
model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', 
activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', 
activation='softmax'))
```